# Pass List to function with (object sender, EventArgs e)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function `RadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged` and in this function i created a list and i want to pass the List to a nother function: `DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`

How can I achieve that?

Comment: How about: `DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(list, null)`

Comment: This is probably not a good idea: instead, create a method that does whatever is needed with the list, and call this method from both SelectedIndexChanged event handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possible solutions:

## Send the List object as the event sender (Not recommended)

You may take advantage that event handlers take an `object` argument, which is the sender of the event. You may use this argument to pass in your list:

```
DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      // You'll have to downcast the object
      List<string> myList = sender as List<string>;
}
```

You would call it like this from your radio button event handler:

```
RadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged(obejct sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(yourCreatedList, null);
}
```

This is not recommended, because this argument is supposed to hold the sender object, which in your case, is your radio button, not a list.

## Create your own EventArgs (Recommended)

You can create your own implementation of `EventArgs`:

```
public class DropDownListEventArgs : EventArgs
{
     public List<string> List;
}
```

You should then modify your event handler signature:

```
DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, DropDownListEventArgs e)
{
      List<string> myList = e.List;
}
```

You would call it like this from your radio button event handler:

```
RadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged(obejct sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(yourRadioButton, new DropDownListEventArgs()
    {
         List = yourCreatedList
    });
}
```

**P.S.**: I'm assuming your list is of type `List<string>`, but it can be of any type.

Answer (score 1):

Create private List variable in the code behind, retrieve your data from database on radiobuttonchanged to that variable, and then just use that variable inside dropdownlist_selectedindexchanged function. I think it is better way than manipulating with (object sender, EventArgs e);

```
private List list1;
```